How can I tell how deep a paint scratch is and if it has reached the metal?
While driving the other evening, I heard a big thunk.  When I got home, I saw that my rear passenger door has a big scratch on it (3" long, 1/8" wide) in the middle of the door. Also the there's a big wide paint scratch close to the rear wheel.
The scratch is white with some yellow.  How do I know if it has reached the metal?

